# Xpath query trying to pull a value from a website table

Tags: python, html, xpath, sec

I am trying to make a loop to go into a list of company profiles on sec.report and gather their "state of Incorporation" but only getting blank results back.

For example, on https://sec.report/Ticker/adbe, I am trying to use the Xpath function to pull out the value "Delaware". I am using the following code, with an xpath that i have double checked on the developer view of google chrome:
**`sec = tree.xpath('//body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/text()')`**

Can someone please show me where i have gone wrong here? is it due to the "state of incorporation" not being being a defined class?

I have also pulled the CIK number for each company but these values are coming through successfully using a very similar code so i'm not too sure where i have gone wrong:
**`sec = tree.xpath('//div[1]/div/h2[1]/text()')`**

Answer (score 0):

your first one would have worked if you used the below but those are brittle xpaths. Hit this site and it will teach you how to write better paths - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

```
//body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]
```

You can try these:

Delaware:

```
//div[@class='panel panel-default'][1]/following::table[1]//td[text()='State of Incorporation']/following-sibling::td
```

CIK:

```
//h2[contains(text(), 'SEC')]
```

Comment: Thanks a million, the xpaths were too brittle. i've updated them now as you have suggested and looks good!